# What is Big Queries maximum row size?

Tags: google-bigquery

When trying to load data into a big query table, I get an error telling me a row is larger than the maximum allowed size.  I could not find this limitation anywhere in the documentation.  What is the limit?  And is there a workaround?

The file is compressed json and is 360M.

Answer (score 5):

2018 update: 100 MB maximum row size. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Answer (score 1):

The maximum row size is 64k. See: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#import

The limitation for json will likely increase soon.

Comment: Thanks, any hint on what that json limit will be?  I've got rows are almost 2MB, wondering if I should wait or if I should shorten all of my field names to single characters.

Comment: It will probably be on the order of a low number of megabytes, but we need to do some internal testing to find the right number.

Answer (score 1):

2013 update: The maximum row size is 1MB, and 20MB for JSON.

See: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#dataformats

Answer (score 0):

2017 update: 10MB for CSV & JSON. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#import

Except 1MB if streaming, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaminginserts